# Apache2 ProxyPass without query string

Tags: apache, security, mod-proxy, proxypass

I want to provide static looking URLs to internal graph generators without passing on potentially malicious query parameters from the client.

I got a `VirtualHost` configuration that looks kinda like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
# ServerName, ServerAlias, SSLEngine, SSLCertificate...

    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass      /graph/great-graph1.png https://some.internal.host/the-graph.png?width=..&height=..&<more params>
    ProxyPass      /graph/great-graph2.png https://other.internal.host/the-graph.png?width=..&height=..&<more params>
</VirtualHost>
```

And it almost works as I want it to. The graphs are loaded from the correct hosts, but two things to not work:

1. The configured query parameters are ignored
2. The query parameters given by the client are passed on to the internal host

I tried adding `noquery` to the end of the line of the `ProxyPass` of which the existence is mentioned [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) but without any effect.

I also tried various `RewriteRule`s (with enabled `RewriteEngine`) but I couldn't figure out the correct approach here as well.